# Can I host a wcf 4.0 website in IIS instead of as an application in IIS?

Tags: wcf

Most examples I see about hosting WCF in IIS have you create an Application under an existing website.  I have a website in IIS, but the website uses a .NET 2.0 app pool, so I can't host the service as an application under the website.  Is it better to create an empty website to just host the service or to create an empty website and then create an application under that empty website to host the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have WCF running as a WebSite in both IIS6 and IIS7, and they work fine. They basically work exactly the same as any ASP.NET site; the .svc files are conceptually similar to .aspx pages, in that IIS calls over to .NET to process them, and all the core WCF stuff is in the assemblies in \bin. The web site is assigned to an App Pool where the actual processes run, just like a normal ASP.NET site. I don't think you need to make an 'Application' in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new website - you can still host WCF in a 2.0 application pool - but in your project you'll need to set the target framework version to 3.5, instead of 4.0.

Comment: I can't change the target to 3.5 or 4.0, so this would not be an option to me.